# Do nested classes cause a garbage collector not to work?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to transfer some of my code from Android Studio Java to Xamarin C#, and I came up with an article that said that one should avoid strongly referencing two classes between them because then the garbadge collector would never dispose any of them.

The alternative suggested was using WeakReference in one of the two classes (preferably the child class if I understood correctly) so as to avoid such a problem.

For example this:

```
public class Header {
    List<Detail> _details = new List<Detail>();
}


public class Detail {
    Header _parent;
}
```

should be ideally changed to this

```
public class Header {
    List<Detail> _details = new List<Detail>();
}


public class Detail {
    WeakReference<Header> _parent;
}
```

What I have been using is this:

```
public class Header {
    List<Detail> _children = new List<Detail>();


    private class Detail {
       Detail() {
           Header.this._children.add(this);
       }

    }
}
```

This means that there is a strong reference to detail from header through its list and one from the detail through Header.this.

Would this cause an issue with the garbadge collector?

If I changed `List<Detail>`  to `List<WeakReference>` would it be better? And if so wouldn't that mean that the Details would get disposed of all the time after some time of them not being used?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: GC can handle cyclic references. It is looking if there is a path from a globally pinned object to the object. If not, it gets cleaned up.

Comment: are you sure about that? because according to this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/#weakreferences you could create objects that the gc couldn't dispose of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No GC problem in your cases. The problem you've read happens when using MVVM, ie a viewmodel class and a view class. The view class should not keep strong  references to any viewmodel properties. This is not true if you're disposing correctly your views (lots of people don't dispose correctly/at all the views).

Btw your java code can be rewritten like this without problem:

```
public class Header {
    List<Detail> _children = new List<Detail>();

    private class Detail {
       public Detail(Header header) {
           header._children.Add(this);
       }
    }
}
```

The Detail object will be disposed as soon as (note: when the next gc collect happens) you remove it from _children.

Comment: but what if I just remove all references to the Header object? will it then dispose both Header and all the Detail objects? or will it never be collected?

Comment: In this case,  all child objects will be disposed. Unless another class of yours references one of them. Not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

> I came up with an article that said that one should avoid strongly referencing two classes between them because then the garbadge (*sic*) collector would never dispose any of them.

If this was an article about C#, specifically, then it was wrong. This is only potentially an issue for reference counting garbage collectors<sup>1</sup>. The .NET GC has never been a reference counting one.

It can detect when whole object graphs are no longer reachable, no matter how many (strong) references they contain referencing other objects in the same graph.

Also, where you say:

> What I have been using is this:

```
public class Header {
    List<Detail> _children = new List<Detail>();


    private class Detail {
       Detail() {
           Header.this._children.add(this);
       }

    }
}
```

I presume you mean this is what you've been doing in Java. In C#, there's no analogous concept to `Parent.this` for nested classes. An instance of a nested class is only associated with an instance of an outer class if you explicitly create such a model.

---

<sup>1</sup>I believe some work has gone into having cycle detectors for reference counting GCs, but I couldn't tell you the current state of the art for this.

Comment: yes that indeed is in java, it is the code I'm trying to convert to c#
As for the article I am talking about, it is this one

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/memory_perf_best_practices/#weakreferences